# Automatically mapping output parameters with Dapper

Tags: sql, dapper

I've been using Dapper to call stored procedures passing it an object. For example:

If I have an object:

```
public int ID { get; set; }    
public int Year { get; set; }
```

I can create this object and pass it to my `Execute` call as the parameters. Dapper automatically maps all of those properties into parameters and executes the stored procedure. Awesome.

What about output parameters? If my object looked like the following how can I get Dapper to populate that property with the output parameter value?

```
public int ID { get; set; }    
public int Year { get; set; }
public int OutputParameter { get; set; }
```

Do output parameters have to be added as `DynamicParameters`?

Comment: I haven't found a way so it sounds like a job for an extension method perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
        DynamicParameters _params = new DynamicParameters();
        _params.Add("@newId", DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
        var result = connection.Execute("[dbo].YourProc", _params, null, null, CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        var retVal = _params.Get<int>("newId");
```

Comment: That's how I'm doing it now. However, what I'm asking is for is the ability to populate the original object without having to specify the output params. I don't have to manually add the parameters to execute an SP. Is there a way of telling Dapper this is an output parameter, grab the value once you execute it.

Answer (score 0):

```
DynamicParameters _params = new DynamicParameters(new {
ID = 123,
Year = 2020,
OutputParameter = 0
});

_params.Add("OutputParameter", 0, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
var result = connection.Execute("[dbo].YourProc", _params,  commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
var retVal = _params.Get<int>("OutputParameter");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've used to create a generic method for calling stored procedures with generic output parameters.

```
public void CallProcedure<I, O>(
    string storedProcedure,
    I inputParameters,
    O outputParameters,
    string connectionId = "Default")
{
    using IDbConnection connection =
        new SqlConnection(_config.GetConnectionString(connectionId));

    var dynamicParameters = new DynamicParameters();

    if (inputParameters != null)
        dynamicParameters.AddDynamicParams(inputParameters);

    if (outputParameters != null)
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in outputParameters.GetType().GetProperties())
            dynamicParameters.Add(prop.Name, 
                prop.GetValue(outputParameters),
                GetDbType(prop.PropertyType),
                ParameterDirection.Output);

    connection.ExecuteAsync(storedProcedure, dynamicParameters,
        commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

    if (outputParameters != null)
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in outputParameters.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            var method = typeof(DynamicParameters)
                .GetMethod("Get")
                .MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { prop.PropertyType });

            var outputParamValue = method.Invoke(dynamicParameters, new object[] { prop.Name });
            prop.SetValue(outputParameters, outputParamValue);
        }
}
```

What you are looking for is the last few lines, below the second `if (outputParameters != null)`

I do not know how fast it is, as this code is a part of a sketch project.

I also asked this question 6 years later, so you can check if anyone answered it here: [Get all stored procedure output parameters using generic type in dapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73455797/get-all-stored-procedure-output-parameters-using-generic-type-in-dapper)

All in all this is a good headsup for dapper team to create a simple method we can call to get all output parameters of a stored procedure, instead of us getting into reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the question was *Do output parameters have to be added as DynamicParameters?*

The answers is - no, you don't have to use `DynamicParameters` class. You can simply create anonymous object and fetch your output parameter value by using final SELECT query.

Assuming you a have a SP with signature `dbo.MyProc @id int, @year int, @parOut int OUTPUT` and your class.

```cs
class MyClass
{
  public int ID { get; set; }    
  public int Year { get; set; }
  public int OutputParameter { get; set; }
}
```

The call should be as follows:

```cs
MyClass myObject = new MyClass { Id = 123, Year = 2023 };
int result;
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
{
    result = connection.QueryFirstOrDefault<int>(
      @"dbo.MyProc @id, @year, @parOut OUTPUT; SELECT @parOut",
      new 
        {
          id = myObject.Id
          , year = myObject.Year
          , parOut = myObject.OutputParameter
        });
    myObject.OutputParameter = result;
}
```