# Get all stored procedure output parameters using generic type in dapper

Tags: c#, dapper

I will basically be asking this question again, 6 years later:
[Automatically mapping output parameters with Dapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34270938/automatically-mapping-output-parameters-with-dapper#)

I have an interface called `IDataAccess` that would encapsulate any framework that is working with the database. It has couple of methods, just for calling stored procedures.

All my 'service' classes (`AccountService`, `CustomerService`, `ProductService`, ...) will be injected with an instance of this `IDataAccess` and will only be using it's methods (so no dapper classes in them, otherwise it wouldn't be a loose coupleing).

I've created a class that implements this interface and is working with an MSSQL database called `SqlDataAccess`.

Sounds fine and dandy, but I can't seem to get output parameters for stored procedures from dapper generically.

Here's what I've tried:

```
public void CallProcedure<I, O>(
    string storedProcedure,
    I inputParameters,
    O outputParameters,
    string connectionId = "Default")
{
    using IDbConnection connection =
        new SqlConnection(_config.GetConnectionString(connectionId));

    var dynamicParameters = new DynamicParameters();

    if (inputParameters != null)
        dynamicParameters.AddDynamicParams(inputParameters);

    if (outputParameters != null)
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in outputParameters.GetType().GetProperties())
            dynamicParameters.Add(prop.Name, 
                prop.GetValue(outputParameters),
                GetDbType(prop.PropertyType),
                ParameterDirection.Output);

    connection.Execute(storedProcedure, dynamicParameters,
        commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

    if (outputParameters != null)
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in outputParameters.GetType().GetProperties())
            // 1st try
            prop.SetValue(outputParameters, dynamicParameters.Get<prop.PropertyType>($"@{prop.Name}"));
            // 2nd try
            prop.SetValue(outputParameters, dynamicParameters.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name));
}
```

**1st try**
is not working because I can't pass `prop.PropertyType` as a generic type, because C# is expecting a hardcoded type, not a variable type.

**2nd try**
is not working because `dynamicParameters` is not populated when I call `connection.Execute(...`

**3rd try**
would be for this method to return `dynamicParameters` variable so that the user of this function can get the result with this syntax `dynamicParameters.Get<int>("some_output_parameter");`, with any type, not just `int`, but that's a no go as I would have to add `using Dapper;` to all my service classes, and that's closely coupling dapper with my services, which beats the purpose of having `IDataAccess`.

It's not the job of this class to expose all stored procedures, but to expose a generic way of calling them. It's job of the service classes to know and call stored procedures that are specific for that service.

##### My question is

How do I get all output parameters from stored procedure that's been called with dapper, generically?

Answer (score 0):

Dapper now provides the `DynamicParameters.Output` function, which allows you to map a single `Expression<Func<T, object>>` to an output parameter.

So your function can accept an array of property or field expressions for the output object, which you can then map to the `DynamicParameters` object.

```cs
private DynamicParameters GetDynamicParameters<TInput, TOutput> (
    TInput inputObject,
    TOutput outputObject,
    params Expression<Func<TOutput, object>>[] outputExpressions
    )
{
    var dp = new DynamicParameters(inputObject);
    foreach (var expr in outputExpressions)
        dp.Output(outputObject, expr);

    return dp;
}

public void CallProcedure<TInput, TOutput> (
    string storedProcedure,
    TInput inputObject,
    TOutput outputObject,
    string connectionId,
    params Expression<Func<TOutput, object>>[] outputExpressions
    )
{
    using var connection =
        new SqlConnection(_config.GetConnectionString(connectionId ??  "Default"));

    var dynamicParameters = GetDynamicParameters<TInput, TOutput>(inputObject, outputObject, outputExpressions);

    connection.Execute(storedProcedure, dynamicParameters,
        commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
}

public async Task CallProcedureAsync<TInput, TOutput> (
    string storedProcedure,
    TInput inputObject,
    TOutput outputObject,
    string connectionId = "Default",
    params Expression<Func<TOutput, object>>[] outputExpressions
    )
{
    using var connection =
        new SqlConnection(_config.GetConnectionString(connectionId ??  "Default"));

    var dynamicParameters = GetDynamicParameters<TInput, TOutput>(inputObject, outputObject, outputExpressions);

    await connection.ExecuteAsync(storedProcedure, dynamicParameters,
        commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
}
```